# How to keep reading a file in different functions and not read the file again from the beginning?

Tags: c++

I'm working on a project with `"main"` function and some other functions.

I want to open the `.data` file in main function and and read it in another function like `"getsize"` and then read the file in `"store_num"`.

First of all, it seems that I have to deliver some parameter or pointer to the functions so that they can recognize the `.data` file.What should I do?

Second, I want the content in file just read once, not reading all the content in the `.data` file once again in every different functions.What should I do?

There may be some errors in my code, but I think it'll be alright to understand my question.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

typedef struct value {
    int x, y, value;
    bool check;
}value;

typedef struct peak {
    int col, row;
}peak;

class testcase {
public:
    void getsize(value*);
    void store_num(int, value*);
    void peaktest(int);
    int row = 1;
    int peak_num = 0;
    void set_peak(int, int);
    value* array;
    peak peak_list[10];
    int row_num, col_num;
};

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    std::fstream myfile("matrix.data", std::ios_base::in);


    testcase* map;
    map->getsize(map->array);
    map->store_num(1, map->array);
    for (int countrow = 2; countrow <= map->row_num; countrow++) {
        map->store_num(countrow,map->array);
        map->peaktest(countrow - 1);
    }
    map->peaktest(map->row_num);


    return 0;
}

void testcase::getsize(value* array) {

    //std::cin >> row_num >> col_num;
    myfile >> row_num >> col_num;
    array = new value[row_num*col_num];
}

void testcase::store_num(int row, value* array) {
    if (row == 1 || row == 2 || row == 3) {
        for (int count = 0; count < col_num; count++) {
            /*std::cin*/ myfile >> (array + (row - 1)*col_num + count)->value;
            (array + (row - 1)*col_num + count)->check = true;
            if (count > 0) {
                if ((array + (row - 1)*col_num + count)->value >
                    (array + (row - 1)*col_num + count - 1)->value) {
                    (array + (row - 1)*col_num + count - 1)->check = false;
                }
                else if ((array + (row - 1)*col_num + count)->value <(array 
 + (row - 1)*col_num + count - 1)->value){
                    (array + (row - 1)*col_num + count)->check = false;
                }
            }
            if (row > 1) {
                if ((array + (row - 1)*col_num + count)->value >
                    (array + (row - 2)*col_num + count)->value) {
                    (array + (row - 2)*col_num + count)->check = false;
                }
                else if ((array + (row - 1)*col_num + count)->value <(array + (row - 2)*col_num + count)->value) {
                    (array + (row - 1)*col_num + count)->check = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        for (int count = 0; count < col_num; count++) {
            /*std::cin*/myfile >> (array + ((row - 1) % 3) + count)->value;
            (array + ((row - 1) % 3) + count)->check = true;
            if (count > 1) {
                if ((array + ((row - 1) % 3) + count)->value > (array + ((row - 1) % 3) + count - 1)->value) {
                    (array + ((row - 1) % 3) + count - 1)->check = false;
                }
                else if ((array + ((row - 1) % 3) + count)->value < (array + ((row - 1) % 3) + count - 1)->value) {
                    (array + ((row - 1) % 3) + count)->check = false;
                }
            }
            if ((array + ((row - 1) % 3) + count)->value > (array + ((row + 1) % 3) + count)->value)
                (array + ((row + 1) % 3) + count)->check = false;
            else if ((array + ((row - 1) % 3) + count)->value < (array + ((row + 1) % 3) + count)->value)
                (array + ((row - 1) % 3) + count)->check = false;
        }
    }
}

void testcase::peaktest(int row) {
    for (int col = 1; col <= col_num; col++) {
        if ((array + (row - 1)*row_num + (col - 1))->check == true)
            set_peak(row, col);
    }
}

void testcase::set_peak(int row ,int col) {
    peak_list[peak_num].row = row;
    peak_list[peak_num].col = col;
    peak_num++;
}
```

Comment: Couple of questions about your code: the file that is read in `matrix.data` is this being read in as text that you have to convert to types or is this being read in as a binary file? The second question is more of a request: could you supply an example of your `matrix.data` file so that others can see what kind of data file you are trying to read in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the file stream by reference into the other functions that need it.

```
class testcase {
public:
    void getsize(value*, std::fstream & myfile);
    void store_num(int, value*, std::fstream & myfile);
    ...
};

int main() {
    std::fstream myfile("matrix.data", std::ios_base::in);

    testcase* map; // Danger Will Robinson! Danger!
    map->getsize(map->array, myfile);
    map->store_num(1, map->array, myfile);
    for (int countrow = 2; countrow <= map->row_num; countrow++) {
        map->store_num(countrow,map->array, myfile);
        map->peaktest(countrow - 1);
    }
    ...
}
```

Regarding the danger message,

```
testcase* map;
```

allocates a pointer to a `testcase`, but doesn't point it a anything. You could

```
testcase* map = new testcase;
```

but there is no need for dynamic allocation here. Consider discarding the pointer.

```
int main() {
    std::fstream myfile("matrix.data", std::ios_base::in);

    testcase map;
    map.getsize(map.array, myfile);
    map.store_num(1, map.array, myfile);
    for (int countrow = 2; countrow <= map->row_num; countrow++) {
        map.store_num(countrow,map.array, myfile);
        map.peaktest(countrow - 1);
    }
    map.peaktest(map.row_num);


    return 0;
}
```

And fixing up that, I see a bug:

```
void testcase::getsize(value* array, std::fstream & myfile) {

    myfile >> row_num >> col_num;
    array = new value[row_num*col_num];
}
```

When you pass in a pointer, the data pointed at, if any, is passed by reference. The pointer itself **is not**. `array` holds a copy of the address used to call `getsize` and is an automatic variable scoped by `getsize`. The allocation assigned to `array` inside the function is lost when `array` goes out of scope. This leaves the value passed in unchanged. Oops. Normally you would

```
void testcase::getsize(value*& array, std::fstream & myfile) {

    myfile >> row_num >> col_num;
    array = new value[row_num*col_num];
}
```

and pass in a reference. But...

I find myself wondering why pass an object's own data into one of its methods? the `testcase` instance already knows `array`. We can assign directly to it. For example

```
void testcase::getsize(std::fstream & myfile) {

    myfile >> row_num >> col_num;
    array = new value[row_num*col_num];
}
```

Next, what if the `testcase` instance already has an allocation when you call `getsize`? `array = new value[row_num*col_num];` leaks it. You want to add a constructor that sets `array` to `nullptr`

```
testcase::testcase(): array(nullptr)
{
}
```

and then

```
void testcase::getsize(std::fstream & myfile) {

    delete[] array;
    myfile >> row_num >> col_num;
    array = new value[row_num*col_num];
}
```

Other possibilities are to overload `operator>>` to read into a `testcase`. Information on that can be found in [What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading) Do that and `getsize` and `store_num` just go away. They are built into `operator>>` and the first few lines of `main` become

```
testcase map;
myfile >> map;
```

Probably more bugs in there, but I'm not looking for them. Instead... I'm going to rant.

```
typedef struct value {
    int x, y, value;
    bool check;
}value;
```

is a C-ism. C++ took advantage of 20 or so years of C and eliminated the need to typedef a `struct` to avoid typing `struct` all the time. C++ knows darn well that `value` is a `struct`, so all you need, other than love, is

```
struct value {
    int x, y, value;
    bool check;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put `std::fstream myfile` in the class itself, and call `myfile.open` with file name in the constructor of the class, or make a method like `init` and call `myfile.open` from there.

If you do like to keep the `myfile` variable in `main`, then pass it to the constructor of `testcase` and have a **reference** variable of type `std::fstream` in the class. This way:

```
class testcase {
std::fstream& _myfile;
public:
testcase(std::fstream& fileArg):_myfile(fileArg){}
```

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to add a class who's single responsibility is to handle I/O from the file in question. Instantiate it in main before you call the other functions, then pass it as a parameter and invoke a public .get() method from it for the next line of data. If you simply put file I/O into your testcase class and had more than one testcase then you either need one data file per object or else each object could be trying to open the same data file. This could also reposition the stream cursor within the file and give you unpredictable results. Better to have one object fulfilling the single responsibility principle.

```
/*---------------------------------

 * FileMgr class

 ----------------------------------*/

class fileMgr
{
private:

    bool open;
    std::string filename;
    std::string buffer;
    std::fstream myfile;

public:

    //-- constructor with filename parameter

    fileMgr(std::string filename)
        : filename(filename)
    {
        buffer = "";    
        myfile = std::fstream(filename, std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::app);

        if(!myfile)
        {
             /*-----------------------------------
             * check to make sure the file opened without
             * any problems, and set a bit flag to tell 
             * which state it is in
             -----------------------------------*/

            std::cerr << "\nERROR: file manager cannot open file: " << filename << std::endl;
            open = false;
        }
        else
        {
            /*---------------------------------------
             * Otherwise it opened fine and we place the 
             * cursor at the beginning of the file
             -----------------------------------------*/

            open = true;
            myfile.clear();
            myfile.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
        }
    }

    //-- function to serve a result row

    value get()
    {
        value newValue;

        if(open)
        {
            std::getline(myfile, buffer);

            //--- parse buffer for your data
        }
        return value;
    }
};
```